# Access a object value within another object

Tags: javascript

I currently have a Object which looks like so:

```
{
    "Best Fare Description": {
        "text": {
            "value": "One",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Brand ID": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Program ID": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Max Elapse Time": {
        "integer": {
            "value": 4,
            "type": "INTEGER"
        }
    },
    "Max Number of Connections": {
        "integer": {
            "value": 5,
            "type": "INTEGER"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through the object and create an array of only the values. So for this object I would return an array of

```
["One","test","test",4,5]
```

What I've Tried:

data being the object

```
      const tempList = [];

      for (var key in data) {
        for (var key2 in data[key]) {
            for (var key3 in data[key][key2]) {
                tempList.push(key3['value'])
                }
            }
        }
```

However it seems like I am not doing something correct, as I get undefined or errors when I push into the array. Is there an easier/More Efficient way to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to loop over the `Object.values` of the two levels using `map` and `reduce` to build your array:

```js
let obj = {"Best Fare Description": {"text": {"value": "One","type": "TEXT"}},"Brand ID": {"text": {"value": "test","type": "TEXT"}},"Program ID": {"text": {"value": "test","type": "TEXT"}},"Max Elapse Time": {"integer": {"value": 4,"type": "INTEGER"}},"Max Number of Connections": {"integer": {"value": 5,"type": "INTEGER"}}}

let arr = Object.values(obj).reduce((arr, item) => {
  arr.push(...Object.values(item).map(inner => inner.value))
  return arr
}, [])
console.log(arr)
```

Newer javascript engines will let you simplify a bit with `flatMap`:

```js
let obj = {"Best Fare Description": {"text": {"value": "One","type": "TEXT"}},"Brand ID": {"text": {"value": "test","type": "TEXT"}},"Program ID": {"text": {"value": "test","type": "TEXT"}},"Max Elapse Time": {"integer": {"value": 4,"type": "INTEGER"}},"Max Number of Connections": {"integer": {"value": 5,"type": "INTEGER"}}}

let arr = Object.values(obj).flatMap(item => Object.values(item).map(inner => inner.value))
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the dynamic keys, you could take the values and map the last item.

```js
var data = { "Best Fare Description": { text: { value: "One", type: "TEXT" } }, "Brand ID": { text: { value: "test", type: "TEXT" } }, "Program ID": { text: { value: "test", type: "TEXT" } }, "Max Elapse Time": { integer: { value: 4, type: "INTEGER" } }, "Max Number of Connections": { integer: { value: 5, type: "INTEGER" } } },
    result = Object.values(data).map(o => Object.values(o)[0].value);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you innermost object's structure stays the same. In that case, you could slightly change your existing code to do something like the following:

```
const tempList = [];
for (let key in data) {
  for (let key2 in data[key]) {
    tempList.push(data[key][key2].value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function that will do what you need (it will work with any shape of object):

```
const findValues => obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key)=>{
  if(key==='value'){
    acc.push(obj[key])
  }else if(typeof obj[key]==='object'){
    acc.push(findValues(obj[key]))
  }
  return acc.flat()
},[])
```

So if your object is:

```
const obj = {
    "Best Fare Description": {
        "text": {
            "value": "One",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Brand ID": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Program ID": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Max Elapse Time": {
        "integer": {
            "value": 4,
            "type": "INTEGER"
        }
    },
    "Max Number of Connections": {
        "integer": {
            "value": 5,
            "type": "INTEGER"
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
findValues(obj) // ["One", "test", "test", 4, 5]
```

A more generic version:

```
const findValues = selector => obj => Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,key)=>{
  debugger
  if(key===selector){
    acc.push(obj[key])
  }else if(typeof obj[key]==='object'){
    acc.push(findValues(selector)(obj[key]))
  }
  return acc.flat()
},[])

findValues('value')(obj) // ["One", "test", "test", 4, 5]
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/yWWJxg

Answer (score -1):

You're saying `tempList.push(key3['value'])`, but `key3` is a string, not an array. You also don't need 3 loops, you only need 2.

```js
let data = {
    "Best Fare Description": {
        "text": {
            "value": "One",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Brand ID": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Program ID": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "TEXT"
        }
    },
    "Max Elapse Time": {
        "integer": {
            "value": 4,
            "type": "INTEGER"
        }
    },
    "Max Number of Connections": {
        "integer": {
            "value": 5,
            "type": "INTEGER"
        }
    }
}

const tempList = [];

for (var key in data) {
  for (var key2 in data[key]) {
      if (data[key][key2]['value'])
        tempList.push(data[key][key2]['value'])
  }
}
  
  console.log(tempList);
```